# Are there only finitely many fixed degree nontrivial polynomial parametrizations of the surface $x^4+y^4=z^4+t^4$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Consider the surface over the rationals
$$ x^4+y^4=z^4+t^4 \qquad (1)$$

Consider parametrizations of form:
$$ f_1(u)^4+f_2(u)^4=f_3(u)^4+f_4(u)^4 \qquad(2) $$
where $f_i$ are polynomials with integer coefficients, pairwise $f_i(u) \ne \pm f_j(u),i \ne j$ and $f_i$ coprime.

Let $d=\max \{\deg(f_i)\}$.

> Q1 For fixed $d$, are there only finitely many parametrizations (2)?

Comment: Dear joro, maybe this is a little more complicated than I thought. Let me delete my previous comment until I get things straight in my mind. (I still don't like the term "parametrizations" in this context, though.)

Comment: @potentiallydense I don't mean complete parametrization, since it might make the
surface rational. Do you suggest changing the wording or editing? Maybe
"partial parametrization" is better?

Comment: I would say "parametrizations of rational curves".

Comment: Trying to prevent deleting comments, $f_i$ are univariate polynomials.
I know (1) is K3 and not rational.

Comment: OK, let me contradict my previous comment (where I was only thinking about actual curves on the surface, not maps). Given one parametrization of a curve as in (2), don't you get infinitely many more with the same degree by making substitutions $u \mapsto au+b$ (for integers $a$ and $b$)?

Comment: More generally you can replace $f_i(u)$ by $(\gamma u+\delta )^df_i(\dfrac{\alpha u+\beta }{\gamma u+\delta } )$.
Up to these substitutions, the answer is positive. Indeed you are looking at rational curves of degree $\leq d$ on your surface; there is a finite number of families of curves of degree $\leq d$, and each family contains finitely many rational curves.

Comment: @abx Thanks, I will accept this as an answer. For the homogenized Pell equation $x^2-Dy^2=z^2$ the parametrization is $x=u^2+D,y=2u,z=u^2-D$. Which are are the finite families of degree $2$?